# Process Multiple Batches in Flat File SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a flat file which contains multiple batches.

I want to read the file into a db table but maintain some reference to the batch each line belongs to.

My thought is to append to each detail row the date/timestamp in the header row from the batch to which each row belongs.

What I have done is read the file into a in-memory recordset and then use the foreach loop container to examine and process each line.

I am stuck on the follwing: 
1. examine each line, determine if it is a header or not
2. append batch header information to each line.

Thanks

Comment: Hi

Can you split the file into smaller chunks using c# in a script task?

Comment: I could.  In this scenario though I want to keep all processing within the SSIS package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms345160%28v=sql.100%29#Y3223)  sample script on MSDN which worked perfectly.  If you are coding in C# initialize your counter variable outside of the function else it will keep reinitalizing everytime the function is called.